# Method Call With parameter

Tags: methods, printing, parameters, call

this  week in my college class we started our chapter on Method Calls and i'm having trouble with it. This is the activity we have in class:
Define a method printFeetInchShort, with int parameters numFeet and numInches, that prints using ' and " shorthand. Ex: myPrinter.printFeetInchShort(5, 8) prints:
5' 8"
Hint: Use " to print a double quote.
This is what I have so far, I don't know if i'm doing it right because i've been having trouble with method calling:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeightPrinter {

   public static void printFeetInchShort(int numFeet, int numInches) {
      System.out.println(numFeet + "" + numInches + "\"");
      

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      HeightPrinter myPrinter = new HeightPrinter();

      // Will be run with (5, 8), then (4, 11)
      myPrinter.printFeetInchShort(5, 8);
      System.out.println("");
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void printFeetInchShort(int numFeet, int numInches) {
      System.out.print(numFeet + "' " + numInches + "\"");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the curly braces to close the `printFeetInchShort` method.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeightPrinter {

   public static void printFeetInchShort(int numFeet, int numInches) {
       System.out.println(numFeet + "' " + numInches + "\"");
   }  //<-- this is missing

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userFeet;
      int userInches;

      userFeet = scnr.nextInt();
      userInches = scnr.nextInt();

      printFeetInchShort(userFeet, userInches);  // Will be run with (5, 8), then (4, 11)
   }
}
```